# How to unit test two objects of different classes which has same data?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have two objects which has same fields.  I want to compare the values of those objects fields. How to do that using Junit?

```
public class DeviceDTO {

private String id;
```

And

```
public class DeviceData {
private String id;
```

I want to compare those object's field values.

Answer (score 3):

```
Assert.assertEquals(myDeviceDTO.getId,myDeviceData.getId);
```

Where myDeviceDTO is an instance of the DeviceDTO class and myDeviceData is an instance of the DeviceData class.

Comment: Sorry I mean there are many fields in those objects. I cant compare all of them.  I just wanna check is there anyway comparing two different objects.

Comment: I suppose you could create a method in each object that outputs an array of Objects[] - for each of the fields in the object that you want to compare.  You could then use assertArrayEquals.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have accessors you must use reflection.

You might want to use [reflection assert](http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-reflectionassert.html). A module of the [unitils](http://www.unitils.org/summary.html) library. Take a look at the javadoc of [ReflectionAssert](http://www.unitils.org/apidocs/org/unitils/reflectionassert/ReflectionAssert.html).

Answer (score 0):

Like Rene suggested. I used the module unitils and worked for me:

Use `assertReflectionEquals(obj1,obj2)`.

If you use maven, you should add this dependency to the pom.xml of the project.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
<artifactId>unitils-core</artifactId>
<version>3.4.2</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```